# Play Framework Error: Unexpected exception ProvisionExceptionUnable to provision

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Can anyone help me in resolving this exception. http://localhost:9000 I get this like when I do sbt run

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Router not found: router.Routes]
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router

1 error]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:165) ~[play-server_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121) ~[play-server_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121) ~[play-server_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119) ~[play-server_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119) ~[play-server_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111) ~[play-server_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Router not found: router.Routes]
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:321) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:316) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.Application$class.routes(Application.scala:111) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.routes(Application.scala:240) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:89) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:156) ~[play-server_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121) ~[play-server_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Router not found: router.Routes]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:829) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.routing.Router$$anonfun$load$2.apply(Router.scala:67) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.routing.Router$$anonfun$load$2.apply(Router.scala:66) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.api.routing.Router$.load(Router.scala:66) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get$lzycompute(BuiltinModule.scala:66) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:63) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:62) ~[play_2.10-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
```

Comment: - this is old project or newly created? scala 2.10 is pretty ancient. Same with play framework (version from 2015). If it is old codebase it will be important what was changed lastly.

Comment: Is this a brand new Play project? Is there something special in the configuration? Maybe you should actually share your configuration file with us.

Comment: Nevertheless error is somehow connected with `routes` file or `Routes` class (depending on what you choose to use) or your configuration. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaRouting

Comment: @Scalway this is old project and I changed to new by following migration docs of sbt like changing from Build.scala to build.sbt file and syntax changes in the build.

Comment: @GaëlJ May I know which configuration file ? routes or application.conf ?

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Router
> not found: router.Routes]

This line in your long error is pretty descriptive. It happens when you have no Routes file or your routes file is empty. [Official docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaRouting#The-routes-file-syntax) have have info where to put that file and what should be inside.